# Select A Line Of Text Using A Shortcut In Text Widget, Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, events, keyboard-shortcuts

I've decided to start on a Tkinter project to get an even better understanding of Tkinter and to expand my knowledge. I've decided to make a notepad and I've managed to do it except a small problem I've bumped into. I want to make a custom shortcut in Tkinter that will help me copy long lines of text without having to scroll a lot. I know there are shortcuts like using `Shift` to copy from where the cursor is, but what I want to do is make my own custom shortcut. Let's say, for example, pressing `Ctrl + Q` will copy the whole line that the cursor is on or something similar. If possible, it would also be a nice feature to be able to `select` the current line without copying it using another custom shortcut. For example, see image:
[image: Select Whole Line]
I've done a lot of research about this problem but I haven't managed to find anything useful as information. I don't want to use a shortcut that already exists in windows, since I want to make my own custom shortcuts. The problem is not about how I use the bind feature, the problem is how I would go about actually making a function that would select the line and copy it.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty simple, you just need to make use of [`Text` widget indices](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html), they provide great functionality. The most useful in this case are `'insert'` and `'linestart'` and `'lineend'` as they easily allow to select the entire line where the cursor is. The rest is pretty simple:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def copy_line(event=None):
    data = text.get('insert linestart', 'insert lineend')
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(data)


def select_line(event=None):
    # `sel` is a special tag name that represents the current selection if any
    text.tag_add('sel', 'insert linestart', 'insert lineend')


root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

text.bind('<Control-q>', copy_line)
text.bind('<Control-e>', select_line)

root.mainloop()
```